# Laravel - I can't find the Authenticate Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I'm new to Laravel and as said in the title I can't find the Authenticate Middleware. I know it should be in app/http/middleware/Authenticate, as it was in previous projects, but it's not there. The ones that are there are: Encrypt.. , RedirectifAuth.. and VerifyCsrf...
I hope you can help me locate it.

Comment: Can you share the codes and can you let me laravel version?

Comment: It is version 5.3.4 . Could it be that they moved it from app/http/middleware/Authenticate to vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware? I just found an Authenticate.php file there, but I thought you shouldn't change the vendor files..

Comment: Did you run `php artisan make:auth` ?

Comment: Im sorry, I was stupid enough to look into the middleware folder of another project so still its not working. When I run the php artisan make:auth command while being in my virtual machine i just get this: Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); in routes/web.php

Comment: Okay so I made a new project and it was missing the authenticate middleware in app/http/middleware/Authenticate too. I think they just moved it like switching from routes.php to web.php.

Comment: Okay so just for the record i finally found a way by using composer to get a project with the file. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a solid understanding of what you're doing it is **not recommended** that you move or overwrite files within the vendor folder.

That being said, you CAN overwrite the Authenticate.php file and just modify your Kernel.php file:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,  <--Change this Directory
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ...
];
```

To:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class, <--- There you go
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ...
];
```

Be sure to copy and paste the code from the Authenticate file in the vendor folder into the Authenticate file in your app\http\middleware directory to resume the same functionality.

Again it's not recommended you do this unless you have a solid understanding of what you're doing and how it all works.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.2

'app/http/middleware/Authenticate.php'

Laravel 5.3

'app/exceptions/handler.php'

Comment: Save me there thank you, am trying to learn  Lavarel I have been stubborn